# kafka connect s3 source not working with Minio

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, minio, s3-kafka-connector

I have verified the connection to minio, making sure that the credentials are working fine and minio is reachable. Also if I try any other value for **store.url = http://minio:9000** I am not able to save the config, so I guess that there is no issue in terms of visibility from **kafka-connect** container and **minio** container. I am not sure if it has anything to do with **DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain** or not.

Any help is appreciated

logs from kafka-connect container

```
01] Starting connector minio (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1321)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,986] INFO [minio|worker] Creating connector minio of type io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:274)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,986] INFO [minio|worker] SourceConnectorConfig values: 

config.action.reload = restart

connector.class = io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector

errors.log.enable = false

errors.log.include.messages = false

errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000

errors.retry.timeout = 0

errors.tolerance = none

header.converter = null

key.converter = null

name = minio

predicates = []

tasks.max = 1

topic.creation.groups = []

transforms = []

value.converter = null

 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:372)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,987] INFO [minio|worker] EnrichedConnectorConfig values: 

config.action.reload = restart

connector.class = io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector

errors.log.enable = false

errors.log.include.messages = false

errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000

errors.retry.timeout = 0

errors.tolerance = none

header.converter = null

key.converter = null

name = minio

predicates = []

tasks.max = 1

topic.creation.groups = []

transforms = []

value.converter = null

 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:372)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,988] INFO [minio|worker] Instantiated connector minio with version 2.2.0 of type class io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:284)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,988] INFO [minio|worker] Finished creating connector minio (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:310)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,988] INFO [minio|worker] Starting storage source connector (io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.GenericStorageSourceConnector:108)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,991] INFO [minio|worker] S3SourceConnectorConfig values: 

aws.access.key.id = 093DrIkcXK8J3SC1

aws.secret.access.key = [hidden]

behavior.on.error = fail

bucket.listing.max.objects.threshold = -1

confluent.license = 

confluent.topic = _confluent-command

confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers = [http://kafka:29092]

confluent.topic.replication.factor = 3

directory.delim = /

file.discovery.starting.timestamp = 0

filename.regex = (.+)\+(\d+)\+.+$

folders = []

format.bytearray.extension = .bin

format.bytearray.separator = 

format.class = class io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat

mode = GENERIC

partition.field.name = []

partitioner.class = class io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner

path.format = 

record.batch.max.size = 200

s3.bucket.name = kafka-connect

s3.credentials.provider.class = class com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

s3.http.send.expect.continue = true

s3.part.retries = 3

s3.path.style.access = true

s3.poll.interval.ms = 60000

s3.proxy.password = null

s3.proxy.url = 

s3.proxy.username = null

s3.region = us-west-1

s3.retry.backoff.ms = 200

s3.sse.customer.key = null

s3.ssea.name = 

s3.wan.mode = false

schema.cache.size = 50

store.url = http://minio:9000

task.batch.size = 10

topic.regex.list = [topic1:.*\.json]

topics.dir = topics

 (io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnectorConfig:372)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,992] INFO [minio|worker] Using configured AWS access key credentials instead of configured credentials provider class. (io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3Storage:491)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,995] ERROR [minio|worker] WorkerConnector{id=minio} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:192)

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

at io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.GenericStorageSourceConnector.start(GenericStorageSourceConnector.java:113)

at io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.CompositeSourceConnector.start(CompositeSourceConnector.java:72)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:184)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:209)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:348)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:331)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

[2022-07-05 15:59:29,996] ERROR [minio|worker] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-01] Failed to start connector 'minio' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:627)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to start connector: minio

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$startConnector$20(DistributedHerder.java:1327)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:334)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to transition connector minio to state STARTED

... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

at io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.GenericStorageSourceConnector.start(GenericStorageSourceConnector.java:113)

at io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.CompositeSourceConnector.start(CompositeSourceConnector.java:72)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:184)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:209)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:348)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:331)

... 7 more
```

connector_minio_config.json

```
{
  "name": "minio",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
    "mode": "GENERIC",
    "store.url": "http://minio:9000",
    "topic.regex.list": "topic1:.*\\.json",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "http://kafka:29092",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "s3.bucket.name": "kafka-connect",
    "s3.region": "us-west-1",
    "aws.access.key.id": "093DrIkcXK8J3SC1",
    "aws.secret.access.key": "CfjqeNxAtDLnUK8Fbhka8RwzfZTNlrf5"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
  elastic_data:
    driver: local
  minio_data1:
    driver: local
  minio_data2:
    driver: local

networks:
  netlocal:
    driver: "bridge"

services:

  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    command: server --console-address ":9001" http://minio/data{1...2}
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    expose:
      - "9000"
      - "9001"
    # environment:
    #   MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
    #   MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
    hostname: minio
    volumes:
      - minio_data1:/data1
      - minio_data2:/data2
    networks:
      - netlocal


  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.0.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: kafka-connect-control-center
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'kafka-connect-01:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - netlocal


  kafka-connect-01:
    # image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0
    container_name: kafka-connect-01
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect-01"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect-01
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-01-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-01-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-01-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        #
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.5.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:11.1.1
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3-source:2.2.0
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost ⏳"
        while : ; do
          curl_status=$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors)
          echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
          if [ $$curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
            break
          fi
          sleep 5 
        done
        sleep infinity

    networks:
      - netlocal


  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - netlocal


  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:2
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - netlocal


  schema-registry:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0"
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS: 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    networks:
      - netlocal
```

Answer (score 4):

The file **connector_minio_config.json** was missing:

```
"tasks.max": "1",
```

This is a bug in the connector, as by default it should be 1.
[image]