# spring cloud data flow - s3 source not working with minio

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, minio

I am running a similar docker-compose of what you can find in the spring docs for running Spring Cloud Dada Flow in your local machine.

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
  elastic_data:
    driver: local
  minio_data1:
    driver: local
  minio_data2:
    driver: local

networks:
  sdf:
    driver: "bridge"

services:

  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    command: server --console-address ":9001" http://minio/data{1...2}
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    expose:
      - "9000"
      - "9001"
    # environment:
    #   MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin       093DrIkcXK8J3SC1
    #   MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin   CfjqeNxAtDLnUK8Fbhka8RwzfZTNlrf5
    hostname: minio
    volumes:
      - minio_data1:/data1
      - minio_data2:/data2
    networks:
      - sdf


  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - sdf


  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:2
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="requests:1:1,responses:1:1,notifications:1:1"
      #- KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - sdf


  dataflow-server:
    user: root
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.9.1}${BP_JVM_VERSION:-}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_STREAMS_BINDER_BROKERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZKNODES=zookeeper:2181
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_STREAMS_BINDER_ZKNODES=zookeeper:2181

      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_KAFKA_STREAMS_PROPERTIES_METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      # Set CLOSECONTEXTENABLED=true to ensure that the CRT launcher is closed.
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_TASK_SPRING_CLOUD_TASK_CLOSECONTEXTENABLED=true

      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI=${SKIPPER_URI:-http://skipper-server:7577}/api

      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      # (Optionally) authenticate the default Docker Hub access for the App Metadata access.
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_CONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_USER=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_USER}
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_CONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_SECRET=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}

      # - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRYCONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_USER=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_USER}
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRYCONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_SECRET=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - skipper-server
    entrypoint: >
      bin/sh -c "
         apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget &&
         wget --no-check-certificate -P /tmp/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh &&
         chmod a+x /tmp/wait-for-it.sh &&
         /tmp/wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- /cnb/process/web"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MOUNT_PATH:-.}:${DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH:-/home/cnb/scdf}
    networks:
      - sdf


  app-import-stream:
    image: springcloud/baseimage:1.0.0
    container_name: dataflow-app-import-stream
    depends_on:
      - dataflow-server
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "
        ./wait-for-it.sh -t 360 dataflow-server:9393;
        wget -qO- '${DATAFLOW_URI:-http://dataflow-server:9393}/apps' --no-check-certificate --post-data='uri=${STREAM_APPS_URI:-https://dataflow.spring.io/kafka-maven-latest&force=true}';
        wget -qO- '${DATAFLOW_URI:-http://dataflow-server:9393}/apps/sink/ver-log/3.0.1' --no-check-certificate --post-data='uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-kafka:3.0.1';
        wget -qO- '${DATAFLOW_URI:-http://dataflow-server:9393}/apps/sink/ver-log/2.1.5.RELEASE' --no-check-certificate --post-data='uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-kafka:2.1.5.RELEASE';
        wget -qO- '${DATAFLOW_URI:-http://dataflow-server:9393}/apps/sink/dataflow-tasklauncher/${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.9.1}' --no-check-certificate --post-data='uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher-sink-kafka:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.9.1}';
        echo 'Maven Stream apps imported'"
    networks:
      - sdf


  skipper-server:
    user: root
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:-2.8.1}${BP_JVM_VERSION:-}
    container_name: skipper-server
    ports:
      - "7577:7577"
      - ${APPS_PORT_RANGE:-20000-20195:20000-20195}
    environment:
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_LOW=20000
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_HIGH=20190
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_DEPLOYER=ERROR
    entrypoint: >
      bin/sh -c "
         apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget &&
         wget --no-check-certificate -P /tmp/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh &&
         chmod a+x /tmp/wait-for-it.sh &&
         /tmp/wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- /cnb/process/web"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MOUNT_PATH:-.}:${DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH:-/home/cnb/scdf}
    networks:
      - sdf


  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.25
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dataflow
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - sdf
```

I was able to add Elasticsearch to this docker-compose and successfully connect to it (using elasticsearch sink), but here I am just keeping what concerns to the issue.

This is how I am configuring the s3 source

```
app.s3.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=093DrIkcXK8J3SC1
app.s3.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=CfjqeNxAtDLnUK8Fbhka8RwzfZTNlrf5
app.s3.cloud.aws.region.static=us-west-1
app.s3.cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
app.s3.common.endpoint-url=http://minio:9000
app.s3.supplier.remote-dir=/kafka-connect/topics
app.s3.logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

[image]

[image]

This is the error that I am getting

```
2022-07-14 14:11:32.625 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2022-07-14 14:11:32.625 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2022-07-14 14:11:32.625 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.626 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 44][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.626 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000
2022-07-14 14:11:32.626 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-44: Shutdown connection
2022-07-14 14:11:32.626 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2022-07-14 14:11:32.626 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 44][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.678 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 45][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-45: Shutdown connection
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2022-07-14 14:11:32.679 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 45][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.704 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2022-07-14 14:11:32.704 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2022-07-14 14:11:32.704 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.704 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 46][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:32.705 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000
2022-07-14 14:11:32.705 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-46: Shutdown connection
2022-07-14 14:11:32.705 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2022-07-14 14:11:32.705 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 46][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 47][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-47: Shutdown connection
2022-07-14 14:11:33.021 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2022-07-14 14:11:33.022 DEBUG [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 47][route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2022-07-14 14:11:33.026 ERROR [s3-source,,] 470 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.s.i.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils      : Error from Flux for : org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource@3d20e22e

org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing '/kafka-connect/topics' to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: kafka-connect.minio
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:348) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:267) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:69) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:47) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils.lambda$messageSourceToFlux$0(IntegrationReactiveUtils.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.onRequest(MonoCreate.java:221) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils.lambda$messageSourceToFlux$1(IntegrationReactiveUtils.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:58) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$6(ReactorSleuth.java:324) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: kafka-connect.minio
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:461) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:341) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: kafka-connect.minio
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5002) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:898) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3Session.list(S3Session.java:91) ~[spring-integration-aws-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3Session.list(S3Session.java:52) ~[spring-integration-aws-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.transferFilesFromRemoteToLocal(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:356) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.lambda$synchronizeToLocalDirectory$0(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:342) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.12.jar!/:5.5.12]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-connect.minio
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy145.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar!/:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Debugging the http connections I can see that is trying to connect to: **http://kafka-connect.minio:9000**

```
Connection request: [route: {}->http://kafka-connect.minio:9000][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
```

This is resulting in an Unknown host as clearly the host **kafka-connect.minio** doesn't exist. But I was able to curl **http://minio:9000** successfully (from inside the skipper-server which is the container that runs the s3 connector).

So here is my question actually:

- Why is it trying to connect to **http://{BUCKET_NAME}.minio:9000** instead of **http://minio:9000** and then go to the bucket?

I am able to connect to this same Minio, to the same bucket with Kafka Connect (s3-source), and I am doing that with a similar approach, meaning, kafka-connect is a separate container in the same docker-compose and it can connect to the minio container and fetch the files. You can see how this is done here [kafka connect s3 source not working with Minio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872816/kafka-connect-s3-source-not-working-with-minio)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this property fixes the problem

```
app.s3.path-style-access=true
```

By default is false, and for the kafka-connect case, by default is true